# While working on building an image segmentation model I am facing a problem of getting dimensions not equal

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am working on an image segmentation problem where training images=50 and testing images=51. I am facing an error where dimensions are not equal.
Input_shape=(256,256,3)
Model Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, MaxPool2D, Conv2DTranspose, Concatenate, Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Reshape, Dense, Multiply, AveragePooling2D, UpSampling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG19

def squeeze_excite_block(inputs, ratio=8):
    init = inputs
    channel_axis = -1
    filters = init.shape[channel_axis]
    se_shape = (1, 1, filters)

    se = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(init)
    se = Reshape(se_shape)(se)
    se = Dense(filters // ratio, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', use_bias=False)(se)
    se = Dense(filters, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='he_normal', use_bias=False)(se)

    x = Multiply()([init, se])
    return x

def ASPP(x, filter):
    shape = x.shape

    y1 = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(shape[1], shape[2]))(x)
    y1 = Conv2D(filter, 1, padding="same")(y1)
    y1 = BatchNormalization()(y1)
    y1 = Activation("relu")(y1)
    y1 = UpSampling2D((shape[1], shape[2]), interpolation="bilinear")(y1)

    y2 = Conv2D(filter, 1, dilation_rate=1, padding="same", use_bias=False)(x)
    y2 = BatchNormalization()(y2)
    y2 = Activation("relu")(y2)

    y3 = Conv2D(filter, 3, dilation_rate=6, padding="same", use_bias=False)(x)
    y3 = BatchNormalization()(y3)
    y3 = Activation("relu")(y3)

    y4 = Conv2D(filter, 3, dilation_rate=12, padding="same", use_bias=False)(x)
    y4 = BatchNormalization()(y4)
    y4 = Activation("relu")(y4)

    y5 = Conv2D(filter, 3, dilation_rate=18, padding="same", use_bias=False)(x)
    y5 = BatchNormalization()(y5)
    y5 = Activation("relu")(y5)

    y = Concatenate()([y1, y2, y3, y4, y5])

    y = Conv2D(filter, 1, dilation_rate=1, padding="same", use_bias=False)(y)
    y = BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = Activation("relu")(y)

    return y

def conv_block(x, filters):
    x = Conv2D(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)

    x = squeeze_excite_block(x)

    return x

def encoder1(inputs):
    skip_connections = []

    model = VGG19(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_tensor=inputs)
    names = ["block1_conv2", "block2_conv2", "block3_conv4", "block4_conv4"]
    for name in names:
        skip_connections.append(model.get_layer(name).output)

    output = model.get_layer("block5_conv4").output
    return output, skip_connections

def decoder1(inputs, skip_connections):
    num_filters = [256, 128, 64, 32]
    skip_connections.reverse()

    x = inputs
    for i, f in enumerate(num_filters):
        x = UpSampling2D((2, 2), interpolation="bilinear")(x)
        x = Concatenate()([x, skip_connections[i]])
        x = conv_block(x, f)

    return x

def output_block(inputs):
    x = Conv2D(1, 1, padding="same")(inputs)
    x = Activation("sigmoid")(x)
    return x

def encoder2(inputs):
    num_filters = [32, 64, 128, 256]
    skip_connections = []

    x = inputs
    for i, f in enumerate(num_filters):
        x = conv_block(x, f)
        skip_connections.append(x)
        x = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(x)

    return x, skip_connections

def decoder2(inputs, skip_1, skip_2):
    num_filters = [256, 128, 64, 32]
    skip_2.reverse()

    x = inputs
    for i, f in enumerate(num_filters):
        x = UpSampling2D((2, 2), interpolation="bilinear")(x)
        x = Concatenate()([x, skip_1[i], skip_2[i]])
        x = conv_block(x, f)

    return x

def build_model(input_shape):
    inputs = Input(input_shape)
    x, skip_1 = encoder1(inputs)
    x = ASPP(x, 64)
    x = decoder1(x, skip_1)
    output1 = output_block(x)

    x = inputs * output1

    x, skip_2 = encoder2(x)
    x = ASPP(x, 64)
    x = decoder2(x, skip_1, skip_2)
    output2 = output_block(x)

    outputs = Concatenate()([output1, output2])
    model = Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_shape = (256, 256, 3)
    model = build_model(input_shape)
    model.summary()
```

And getting the following error while training my model :
ValueError: in user code:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:855 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
<ipython-input-10-88ab9377d655>:15 dice_coef  *
    intersection = tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:1250 binary_op_wrapper
    raise e
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:1234 binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:1575 _mul_dispatch
    return multiply(x, y, name=name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:530 multiply
    return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py:6250 mul
    "Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:750 _apply_op_helper
    attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:601 _create_op_internal
    compute_device)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:3565 _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:2042 __init__
    control_input_ops, op_def)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1883 _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 65536 and 131072 for '{{node mul_1}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](flatten/Reshape, flatten_1/Reshape)' with input shapes: [?,65536], [?,131072]
```

Any help regarding this would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs at this line

```
x = Multiply()([init, se])
```

The reason for the error is that `Multiply()` does an element-wise multiplication and hence the dimension of `init` and `se` should be same. In you case the `init` is a output of a `BatchNorm` on `Conv2D` and hence will have a shape like `(1, x, y, filters)` where as the `se` is the output from a dense layer and hence will have a shape like `(1, filters)` here you have defined `filters` as the number of neurons in the last Dense layer. Now you have to reshape the output from the `Dense` layer to match the `init`. Also, if your x and y are not equal to 1 then there will be a dimension mismatch and you will get the error.